# How to store and fetch large text data from SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an android project. Its a tutorials app in which I am providing 100 chapters. But I am not getting exactly how to store these chapters in my app's local database and how to fetch it on button click. I want to provide the facility on button click the next activity must be opened and the contents of the chapters must be loaded on that activity.
  For Example. If I click on Button "Chapter 1" then 1st chapter must be loaded from SQlite database.
 I have followed lots of tutorials but I am not satisfied. Please Somebody Help Me.

Comment: Really? Show the table creation code or something... how are you inserting? how are you trying to retrieve the data? what´s your layout? buttons? activities?

Comment: are you asking about db schema?

Comment: @WASEEMA you can just store these chapters in zip files, for example, `chapter1.zip`, `chapter2.zip`. just place them in `raw` folder and read contents with input stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

- TEXT type - SQLite supports very long text.

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9

> SQLite will be happy to store a 500-million character string there

- BLOB type: If you don't want to use TEXT, you can use BLOB instead ( You need to convert the large text to a byte array when inserting/updating, and convert the byte array to back to the large text back later)

For database design. You can do like this:

```
- Book table ( _id, name, ...)

- Chapter table (_id, content (TEXT,BLOB), book_id, chapter_number, ...);
```